# WPF - My application installer is crashing

Tags: wpf, installation

Its a .NET 3.5, x86 application that I built. It works. But when I try to install it using a custom installer, it fails with this error `The App has stopped working`. In the dialog box, it shows path to two files. In one of the files, I found this.

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>app.installer.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>5321e224</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>App.Installer</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>1.0.0.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>5321e224</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>4</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>e</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

Is there a way I can find what file was not found for `Parameter8` above?

In the other file, I found this `Exception Code: 0xe0434f4d` but that didn't help much either.

Update:
I'm installing by adding a separate project that is pointing to the `.application` file of the actual app like below.

```
try
{
    Uri deploymentUri = new Uri(deployManifestUriStr);
    iphm = new InPlaceHostingManager(deploymentUri, false);
}
```

Comment: Clearly more of a problem with the installer package you are creating as opposed to WPF. How do you create the package? Can you show some code for that side?

Comment: did you try looking in the event viewer on the machine?  that may give some indication as to which file is missing.

Comment: I tried that too and this is what I found. No missing file name.
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing a dll. I tried copying that dll to the folder where exe was being run from and it works. But I couldn't still figure out how to find the NAME of the missing file. I just found out it was missing a dll by trial and error.
Unless I get a better answer, this is the answer, I guess. Make sure you have all dlls the exe is expecting in the exe directory.